# Separating the operation method from the result

Tags: language-agnostic, methods

I more than once saw code of the form:

```
DiceThrower dt = new DiceThrower();
dt.throw(); //this is a void method
int result = dt.getResult();
```

instead of

```
DiceThrower dt = new DiceThrower();
int result = dt.throw();
```

My question is...why? Isn't it better to have the `throw` method returning the result? By not doing so, I could even incurr in sometimes forgetting about calling `throw()` before `getResult()`, accessing always old values of `getResult()`. Having both the operation and the result in the same method would circumvent that.

What is your oppinion on the matter?

Thanks

Comment: `throw`! bad choice of method name - whatever your language  :-) maybe `roll`?
Oh - sorryy that's the joke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this pattern if you would need to use the data often, and it's expensive to (re)generate. But then memoization would probably be better, so the caller doesn't have to care.

Answer (score 1):

You could even support both. Throw could return the value but it would also be available via getResult(). As noted above, if it's expensive to throw you want to cache the value in case it's needed more than once.